# How to make method return type of generated class in KotlinPoet?

Tags: kotlinpoet

I need to generate a `Builder` class with the help of `KotlinPoet`. For this purpose, I need to make the method return the `Builder` type. I do it in the following way:

```
    private fun generateInitUserBehaviorClass() = TypeSpec.classBuilder("Init")
    .addType(generateInitBuilderClass())
    .build()

private fun generateInitBuilderClass() = TypeSpec.classBuilder("Builder")
    .addProperty(generateInitBuilderEndpointProperty())
    .addFunction(generateInitBuilderEndpointSetter())
    .build()

private fun generateInitBuilderEndpointProperty() = PropertySpec.builder(
    "endpoint",
    Class.forName("android.net.Uri").asTypeName().copy(nullable = true),
    KModifier.PRIVATE
).mutable(true)
    .initializer("null")
    .build()

private fun generateInitBuilderEndpointSetter() = FunSpec.builder("setEndpoint")
    .addParameter("endpoint", Class.forName("android.net.Uri"))
    .returns(Class.forName("com.idfinance.userbehavior.utils.Init.Builder"))
    .build()
```

But when I build the module I catch the error that `Class.forName("com.idfinance.userbehavior.utils.Init.Builder")` cannot find class `Builder`. The package is correct and as I understand the problem is that I try to use class as return type when it is not generated yet. But how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just instantiate a `ClassName` using its [constructor](https://square.github.io/kotlinpoet/1.x/kotlinpoet/kotlinpoet/com.squareup.kotlinpoet/-class-name/index.html#-930159300%2FConstructors%2F434084118), it does not have to be a declared class:

```
private fun generateInitBuilderEndpointSetter() = FunSpec.builder("setEndpoint")
    .addParameter("endpoint", ClassName("android.net", "Uri"))
    .returns(ClassName("com.idfinance.userbehavior.utils", "Init", "Builder"))
    .build()
```